# Status of CheckBox can't be detected

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

i have a problem with detecting status of a checkbox. I have a Grid View With checkbox in it. Ad i need to retrieve a certain value from a selected row to pass it to the query.

But the problem is when I iterate through the GridView lines I can't determine which checkbox is selected and which is not. The process simply doesn't enter this conditional statement:

```
Dim chk As CheckBox  
 ....
        chk = CType(rowItem.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
        If chk.Checked Then
            Primaryid &= GridView1.DataKeys(rowItem.RowIndex)("account_id").ToString()
        End If
```

I also Tried this type of conditionals statement. But it doesn't work as well:

```
Dim Chkb As CheckBox = (CType(gvr.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox))
        If Chkb IsNot Nothing AndAlso Chkb.Checked Then
            Primaryid = gvr.Cells(0).Text
        End If
```

This is function of the VB backEnd code for the button which triggers the execution:

```
Protected Sub RegBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles RegBtn.Click
    Dim Primaryid As String = "Initial stage"
    Dim chk As CheckBox  

    For Each rowItem As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        chk = CType(rowItem.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
        If chk.Checked Then
            Primaryid &= GridView1.DataKeys(rowItem.RowIndex)("account_id").ToString()
        End If
    Next

    Dim exmess As String = "alert('" & Primaryid & "')"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", exmess, True)

End Sub
```

This is how I populate the GridView:

```
        Dim StrQwery As String = "SELECT account_id, account_name bla bla bla"       
        Dim smd As MySqlCommand
        smd = New MySqlCommand(StrQwery, myconn)
        smd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(smd)
        Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)

        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

and this is the code for the Grid View in front Part:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Width="1500px">
        <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" textAlign="right"  /> 
                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>


          </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I really can't understand what am I doing wrong and what should i change to achieve the result. Would be immensely grateful if you can help me with it.

Comment: Are you sure `CheckBox1` is in `Cells[0]`? The first column often has buttons like select. Debug and check if you see it in the Controls collection

Comment: no matter what cell value I put it still returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

in this loop

```
 For Each rowItem As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    chk = CType(rowItem.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
    If chk.Checked Then
        Primaryid &= GridView1.DataKeys(rowItem.RowIndex)("account_id").ToString()
    End If
Next
```

change from

```
  chk = CType(rowItem.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
```

to

```
  chk = CType(rowItem.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
```

also this is not possible

```
Dim Chkb As CheckBox = (CType(gvr.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox))
```

instead try this

```
Dim Chkb As CheckBox = (CType(rowItem.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox))
```

Comment: no I've just tried . The alert message returns nothing. I still can't retrieve the id value

Comment: I'm almost desperate. Trying everything but it doesn't work. And the wierdest thing I can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: on the button clock you try this... GridView1.Rows.count();

Comment: What do you mean on button clock? Should i add an event to button click?

Comment: the for loop is actialy working. If I place `Primaryid = gvr.Cells(1).Text` it actually returns the id value of the last entry in the GridView

Comment: the bloody code is simply doesn't enter a conditional statement for some mysterious reason

Comment: is primaryid a label inside your gridview?

Comment: meks,can u paste your whole gridview design source?

Comment: I've tried the `GridView1.Rows.count()` it returns correct number of rows

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but what is  primaryid?

Comment: and this is the query string `SELECT a.account_id AS 'No', a.accountid_number AS 'ID', a.account_type AS 'Type', CONCAT(account_name,' ',account_midname,' ',account_surname ) AS 'Student Name', a.account_type As 'Type', a.account_birthdate AS 'BirthDate', l.mail AS 'Acount Name',  l.gender AS 'Gender', l.position AS 'Position',  l.office_tel AS 'Tel No', l.alternate_email AS 'Other Email' FROM account a, Leaccount l WHERE a.account_id = l.l_account_id AND l.registered = 'NOTREGISTERED' ORDER BY a.account_id Desc"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084274/cant-determine-status-of-checkbox-in-grid-view  go through this link

Comment: Sharad id I add `DataKeyNames="account_id"` to the gridView it is not populated by anything. only headers are present

Comment: no you need to create a template field for account_id same as checkbox and if you dont want to display t you cn hide that template field. then only u cn fetch the account_id inside the button click

Answer (score 0):

hi try this code inside the button click action

```
 For Each rowItem As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    If rowItem.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim chk As CheckBox = TryCast(rowItem.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
        Dim lbl As Label = TryCast(rowItem.FindControl("primarylbl"), Label)

        Dim Primaryid As String = Nothing
        If chk.Checked Then
            Primaryid += lbl.Text
        End If
    End If
Next
```

it will work

Comment: where is `primarylbl` coming from? Should i declare it in the front part?

Comment: there is a problem in this line: `Dim Primaryid As String = Nothing` the error message is: "primaryid hides a variable in an enclosing block"

Comment: I've tried this code. Doesn't work as well I don't know what to do already